# 'Accessing data with MySQL' Spring guide is broken out of the box?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

Referring to the tutorial/guide at https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/, I downloaded [gs-accessing-data-mysql-main.zip](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-mysql/archive/main.zip).

That ZIP file contains two projects in the following subfolders:

- initial (empty)
- complete (complete, per tutorial, ready to build & run)

Using the latest `IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1`, I opened the `complete` project. It should have at least build without error but, instead, it issues a barrage of error messages that I have no idea how to fix them:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'accessing-data-mysql'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.0.0
      > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.4.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
          - Variant 'mavenOptionalApiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.0.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
          - Variant 'mavenOptionalRuntimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.0.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

If you download [gs-accessing-data-mysql-main.zip](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-mysql/archive/main.zip) and repeat the few steps that I outlined, you can easily reproduce the issue.

In the same `Build` window, below the aforementioned messages, there is a corresponding stacktrace (too long to fit into a post).

Note: I verified the project is set properly to `Java 17`:
[image]

My questions are two:

1. What is the root cause of this problem?
2. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause and fixed it. For the benefit of others (who may be chasing their tail like me), I am posting my findings here.

1. The root cause is the "Gradle build system" using the environment JAVA_HOME (Java 8) instead of using what I configured in IntelliJ's `Project Structure` > `Project Settings` > `Module` (Java 17) -- despite running all under the IDE.
2. The fix is to set Java 17 in yet another location in IntelliJ's settings: `File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Gradle`.

[image: yet another Java location in IntelliJ]

To avoid waste of valuable time like I had, it is great to have one and only JDK/JRE version installed in the development system. This is, however, not always possible, when working on different projects and using various tools (requiring different versions of Java) simultaneously.

The following commands can help figuring out which java/javac are installed on a Windows development environment:

```
C:\>dir /s /n /b java.exe
```

```
C:\>dir /s /n /b javac.exe
```